# Two monitors, two DP-connectors, Ubuntu sees those as one

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, displayport

I have a IBM ThinkPad in a dockingstation. Attached are two monitors (default resolution: 1920x1200) via two DisplayPort connectors.

The laptop have Nvidia/Intel chipset, but I only using Intel. nouveau did not work, and the nVidia driver did work, but was really buggy. With the Intel-driver, almost everything works, except for the following problem:

Ubuntu sees only one DisplayPort and one monitor, but uses both. Before any configuration, I get the same picture (1920x1200) on both monitors. It's a mirror display, however, Ubuntu says it's only seeing one monitor with that resolution. (Ubuntu are unaware of the mirroring)

But, I can choose a resolution of 3840x1200, which give me one big desktop spanning both monitors. But the problem is that the middle of the screen is right between the desktops. Maximizing a window is also spanning across both monitors.

Is there a way to split the one monitor/screen Ubuntu believe is there, into two equal monitors?

BTW, here is the output of xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2880x1620      60.0 +   50.0  
   2048x1536      60.0  
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      60.0  
   1920x1080      59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 3840x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0 +
   3840x1200      60.0* 
   2560x1024      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 disconnected
DVI-D-1-1 disconnected
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (x86_64)

Comment: Have you disabled "nVidia Optimus" in the BIOS?  There are some reports that this causes problems and that the nVidia driver will work if you set the BIOS to "Discrete Graphics Only".

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem. It happened when I switched my video card driver from the proprietary one to the open source one. Ubuntu only saw one monitor and the image was mirrored across both. Tried a bunch of different solutions, nothing worked, finally switched back to the proprietary driver and that fixed it again.

Comment: not really an answer, the OP has tried different drivers already so it is not likely this will help him.